# Find first and last day for previous calendar month in SQL Server Reporting Services (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, date, reporting-services, calendar

I'm creating a report in MS SQL Server Reporting Services and need to set the default Start and End Date report parameters to be the first and last dates of the previous calendar month and need help.

The report is generated on the 2nd calendar day of the month and I need values for:

> Previous Calendar Month
>   - first day
>   - last day

I've been working with DateAdd, but have not been successful at creating an Expression (in VB.NET as I understand it). I would really appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 84):

Randall, here are the VB expressions I found to work in SSRS to obtain the first and last days of any month, using the current month as a reference:

First day of last month:

```
=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

First day of this month:

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

First day of next month:

```
=dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

Last day of last month:

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

Last day of this month:

```
=dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

Last day of next month:

```
=dateadd("m",2,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

The [MSDN documentation for the VisualBasic `DateSerial(year,month,day)` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) explains that the function accepts values outside the expected range for the `year`, `month`, and `day` parameters. This allows you to specify useful date-relative values. For instance, a value of 0 for `Day` means "the last day of the preceding month". It makes sense: that's the day before day 1 of the current month.

Comment: Last day of this month and last day of next month are incorrect; both assume that months to come have the same number of days as the preceding month.  See @Stephanie Grice's answer for a better way to do this in an SSRS expression.

Answer (score 41):

These functions have been very helpful to me - especially in setting up subscription reports; however, I noticed when using the Last Day of Current Month function posted above, it works as long as the proceeding month has the same number of days as the current month.  I have worked through and tested these modifications and hope they help other developers in the future:

Date Formulas:
Find the First Day of Previous Month:

```
DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1))
```

Find Last Day of Previous Month:

```
DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 0)
```

Find First Day of Current Month:

```
DateSerial(Year(Today()),Month(Today()),1)
```

Find Last Day of Current Month:

```
DateSerial(Year(Today()),Month(DateAdd("m", 1, Today())),0)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Dim thisMonth As New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1)
Dim firstDayLastMonth As DateTime
Dim lastDayLastMonth As DateTime

firstDayLastMonth = thisMonth.AddMonths(-1)
lastDayLastMonth = thisMonth.AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: +1 for storing the "reference date" in a variable, which eliminates the (quite unlikely, but possible) condition where there is a month shift between calculating the first and last day.

Comment: I've not seen this in production, but I have seen a broken scheduled build for exactly this reason. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with SSRS, but you can get the beginning and end of the previous month in VB.Net using the `DateTime` constructor, like this:

```
Dim prevMonth As DateTime = yourDate.AddMonths(-1)

Dim prevMonthStart As New DateTime(prevMonth.Year, prevMonth.Month, 1)
Dim prevMonthEnd As New DateTime(prevMonth.Year, prevMonth.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(prevMonth.Year, prevMonth.Month))
```

(`yourDate` can be any `DateTime` object, such as `DateTime.Today` or `#12/23/2003#`)

Answer (score 3):

in C#:

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1)
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: You can just change `new` to `New` and call it VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

I was having some difficulty translating actual VB.NET to the Expression subset that SSRS uses. You definitely inspired me though and this is what I came up with.

```
StartDate  
=dateadd("d",0,dateserial(year(dateadd("d",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))),month(dateadd("d",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))),1))

End Date
=dateadd("d",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

I know it's a bit recursive for the StartDate (first day of last month). Is there anything I'm missing here? These are strictly date fields (i.e. no time), but I think this should capture leap year, etc.

How did I do?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a simple answer to solve this myself. here is what I found

This will split the year and month, take one month off and get the first day.

```
firstDayInPreviousMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate) - 1, 1)
```

Gets the first day of the previous month from the current

```
lastDayInPreviousMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate), 0)
```

More details can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227522%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This one will give you date no time:

```
=FormatDateTime(DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1)), 
DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

This one will give you datetime:

```
=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim aDate As DateTime = #3/1/2008# 'sample date
    Dim StartDate As DateTime = aDate.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-(aDate.Day - 1))
    Dim EndDate As DateTime = StartDate.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(StartDate.Year, StartDate.Month) - 1)

    'to access just the date portion
    ' StartDate.Date
    ' EndDate.Date
```